# jQuery next and previous JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a small interactive, using HTML,CSS and jQuery - Nothing to special.

I have a function that successfully get question data from a json file, but when clicking next or previous the button functions does not seem to trigger and get the next questions data from the array.

Any and all help on this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<div class="two">
  <h2>Question 1</h2>
  <h3></h3>
  <ul class="anwsers">
  </ul>
  <ul class="controls">
    <li class="back">
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
      <button>Next</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function questions(){
  var data = [];
  var index = 1;

  function question() {
    $(".two h3").html(data[index].question);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: '../json/data.json',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      data = json;
      question();
    }
  });

  $('.two li.next button').on('click', function(index){
    console.log(index);
    if (index < data.length - 1) {
      index += 1;
      question();
    }
  });
  $('.two li.back button').on('click', function(index){
    console.log('Prev');
    if (index > 0) {
      index -= 1;
      question();
    }
  });

}
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "1": {
    "question": "Which one of the five is least like the other four?",
    "values": ["Snake", "Rat", "Lion", "Pig", "Cow", "Goat"],
    "answer": "Snake"
  },
  "2": {
    "question": "Which number should come next in the series?<br/>1 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 5 - 8 - 13",
    "values": ["8", "13", "21", "26", "31"],
    "answer": "21"
  },
  "3": {
    "question": "Which one of the five choices makes the best comparison?<br/>PEACH is to HCAEP as 46251 is to",
    "values": ["25641", "26451", "12654", "51462", "15264"],
    "answer": "15264"
  }
}
```

Comment: from where did you get the index value in the callback function of the events?

Comment: you are calling  question(); in you events but from what data?

Comment: man you code doesn't make any sense ,where is your html?

Answer (score 0):

declare  `var data = [];` out of `questions()` function. Make it global

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite it like this:

```
var data = []; var index = 0;

function question() {
    if(data[index] != undefined)
    {        
        $(".two h3").html(data[index].question); 
    }
}

function questions() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../json/data.json',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            data = json;
            question();
        }
    });    
}

$('.two li.next button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(index);
    if (index < data.length - 1) {
        index += 1;
        // enabling the buttons would be useful here
        question();
    } else {
        alert("No more questions");
    }
}); 

$('.two li.back button').on('click', function() {
    console.log('Prev');
    if (index > 0) {
        index -= 1;
        question();
    } else {
        alert("This is the first one.");
    } 
});
```

Comment: I tried this but all I'm getting is console log messages 

`Live reload enabled.
app.js:36 r.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: button, currentTarget: button, relatedTarget: null…}
app.js:36 r.Event {originalEvent: MouseEvent, type: "click", target: button, currentTarget: button, relatedTarget: null…}
3app.js:45 Prev`

Comment: Oh, you can't use index as your event target. Remove them from inside the parantheses. I'll update now.

Comment: I got the following error message app.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefined

Comment: Live reload enabled.
app.js:60 []
app.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'question' of undefinedquestion @ app.js:20success @ app.js:30i @ jquery.js:2fireWith @ jquery.js:2A @ jquery.js:4(anonymous function) @ jquery.js:4
app.js:36 0
app.js:47 Prev

Comment: I added a check for the question method.

Answer (score 0):

Remove index parameter from click even function because 1st parameter in click event handler contain even data.

Because "index" is directly accible under this function :

```
 $('.two li.next button').on('click', function(){
    console.log(index);
  });
  $('.two li.back button').on('click', function(){
console.log(index);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '../json/data.json',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json) {
      data = json;
      $.each(data,function(i,v){
          var answ = '';
          $.each(v.values,function(x,t){ answ +='<li>'+t+'</li>'; });
         $('body').append('
<div class="two" style="display:none;"><h2>Question '+i+'</h2><h3 style="display:none;">'+v.question+'</h3><ul class="anwsers">'+answ+'</ul>
  <ul class="controls">
    <li class="back">
      <button>Back</button>
    </li>
    <li class="next">
      <button>Next</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>');
      });
      $('.two:first').show();
    }
  });

  $('body').on('click','.two li.next button', function(index){
   $(this).closest('.two').hide();
   if($(this).closest('.two').is('.two:last')) {
    $('.two:first').show();
   } else {
    $(this).closest('.two').next().show();
   }
  });
  $('body').on('click','.two li.back button', function(index){
   $(this).closest('.two').hide();
   if($(this).closest('.two').is('.two:first')) {
    $('.two:last').show();
   } else {
    $(this).closest('.two').prev().show();
   }
  });
```

Demo:https://jsfiddle.net/9crboc3b/

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.two li.next button').on('click', function(index){
    console.log(index); //index is a event not the index you defined
    if (index < data.length - 1) {
        index += 1;
        question();
    }
});
```

you can change the function(index) to function(event) that is fine